# After insertion sendToBack image

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that is working regarding insertion of a photo, but I can't send it to back.

I've tried from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782065/excel-2007-image-doesnt-go-to-back) to copy line .ZOrder, but I am operating with object not shape..

Here is mine code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()
Dim p As Object
Dim rng0 As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set rng0 = Range("Q3:S5")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If UserForm1.txtImage = "" Then


rng0.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous

 
Exit Sub
Else
sh.Range("Q3:S5").Merge
Set p = sh.Pictures.Insert(UserForm1.txtImageBackground)
sh.Shapes(p.name).LockAspectRatio = False

If rng0.Cells.Count = 1 Then Set rng0 = rng0.MergeArea
With rng0
    p.Top = .Top
    p.Left = .Left
    p.Width = .Width
    p.Height = .Height
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
Application.ScreenUpdating = True




'        shp.ScaleHeight Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
'        shp.ScaleWidth Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
'        shp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a `Picture` so you can use `ZOrder` on it directly:

```
p.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Edit: my mistake. `Zorder` is a property for Pictures and is read-only. You need:

```
p.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

Comment: I am getting on that line an error '1004' - ZOrder method of  Picture class failed.

Comment: the code is working! But I dont know is it the right thing that I want. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/taww6emaadrl663/send%20to%20back.jpg?dl=0) I want just to text can be typed over the image. Is that possible? I've heard that excel not support that as MS Word does? Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't put pictures behind cells. The closest you can do is to put a sheet background in, which will repeat one picture as required.

Comment: Just one question more - Can I "resize" background, not to be streched across all sheet, just from cell e.g. C6:N20 ?

Comment: Nope, afraid not. You could alter your image to include a lot of white space (it would still repeat but probably off screen) but that's it.